# Android Listview issues in adding data from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using android listview with lazyadapter to show images and textview in list.

and when user scrolls to the bottom i am using AsyncTask to add more contents but when i execute AsyncTask it kills the process.

here is my code.
**mainactivity**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.sax.Element;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends Activity {

    // url to make request


    // JSON Node names
    static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "comics";
    static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    static final String TAG_NAME = "title";
    static final String TAG_EMAIL = "id";
    static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "image";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;
    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    static int counter = 0;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                    // call the function
    LoadData();

}

public void LoadData(){


      String url = "http://myurl?start=" + counter;


            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {
                // Getting Array of Contacts
                contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String mobile = "http://www.funnydash.com/uploads/s/" + c.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    // Phone number is agin JSON Object

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    contactList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */

            // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, contactList);        
            list.setAdapter(adapter);



            list.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());

}

public class BackgroundLoadMore extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

      @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Showing progress dialog before sending http request


        }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        LoadData();

        return (null);


    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // On completing background task
        // closing progress dialog etc,.
        list.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());

        }

}

      public class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

            private int visibleThreshold = 0;
            private int currentPage = 0;
        private int previousTotal = 0;
        private boolean loading = true;

        public EndlessScrollListener() {
        }
        public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
            this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (loading) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    counter +=12;
                }
            }
            if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                // I load the next page of gigs using a background task,
                // but you can call any function here.
                new BackgroundLoadMore().execute();
                loading = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }
    }
```

}

**Lazyadapter.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 



    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name

        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);



        // Setting all values in listview

    title.setText(song.get(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.TAG_NAME));
    artist.setText(song.get(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.TAG_ID));

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.TAG_PHONE_MOBILE), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

}

and [this](http://pastebin.com/XiUpci64) is what i get in my logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you're attempting to set an adapter on your list from outside the UI thread. Views in Android can **not** be modified in a background thread, which in this case, means you can not modify the UI from the `doInBackground` method of an `AsyncTask`. So, your method `LoadData()` can't call the following:

```
adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, contactList);        
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());
```

You will need to return some data (probably `contactList`) from your `doInBackground()` method, and then move the offending code to the `onPostExecute()` method, which **is** run on the UI thread.

The key problem noted in the stack trace is:

```
CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a view off the main thread class.

As said on this line

> 07-26 22:26:36.933: E/AndroidRuntime(16353): Caused by:
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Your main problem is here in your asyncTask. You can not create view items that are not in the original thread. What you can do. is to place this lines on your post method not in do background method or outside asynctask class.

```
        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, contactList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Always keep the **UI thread work on the UI thread, and Non-UI work on the Non-UI thread**, this became a **law from the arrival of the Honey Comb version of Android.**

**2.** From your above logcat, it points to only one thing, that you are **trying to do something from the Non-UI thread on the UI thread (The main Dedicated UI thread).**

**Here it is.... You are calling it on the doInBackground() which is a Non-UI thread.**

```
adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, contactList);        
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());
```

**3. Modify the adapter form UI thread, you can do it in** `onPostExecute()`